# Django log file permissions

Tags: python, django, apache, logging

I have a django project with a logger. The log file becomes huge quite fast. Here is my settings for the logger:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
        "post_office": {
            "format": "[%(levelname)s]%(asctime)s PID %(process)d: %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/opt/bitnami/djangocms_projects/bell_cms/Bell_cms.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*5, # 5 MB
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        "post_office": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "post_office"
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'scheduler_app': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        "post_office": {
            "handlers": ["post_office"],
            "level": "INFO"
        },
    }
}
```

I have 2 issues, first the file doesn't split with `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler`. For example now it is 330 MiB. Second, if I where to erase the file and let django re-create it, my apache server would crash saying that it doesn't have permissions on the log file. The file has root ownership. Is there a way to either have it create the file under a user's ownership (so apache can read by default) or is there a way to automatically grant certain permissions for this file. Right now my fix is to delete, chmod 777 that file and restart apache.

Comment: Which user/group owns the directory containing the log file? It sounds like Apache doesn't have permission to create a new file. It's probably a better idea to change the owner of the log file to `www-data` (or change the group to one that contains `www-data`) instead of changing the permissions to 777.

Comment: ATM the file is owned by root folder is owned by bitnami, and i think apache running under bitnami. The problem is not assigning the permissions or changing them, but rather have it create a file with specific (not default) permissions

Comment: I was trying to point out that if you fix the folder's ownership/permissions so that the files are rotated, then you won't need to create files or change their permissions any more.